# TypeError: window.scroll is not a function TypeError: window.scroll is not a function in server side rendering

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, angular-universal

i cloned an angular universal project for server side rendering and routing also works fine but each time i click on view source page it through the following error and the page doesn't load.(i am sending data to hit api in formdata).

whenever i hit view source page, console shows this error

> ERROR { Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: FormData is not
>   defined ReferenceError: FormData is not defined
>       at BodyWisdomComponent.getAllBodyWisdom (webpack:///./dist-server/main.095f1696d45b5b44a263.js?:1:10104)

i use formdata for sending my data to server in api.:

```
var myFormData = new FormData();
myFormData.append('timezone', 'asia/kolkata');
myFormData.append('page_no', this.pageNumber);
```

My webpack.config.js file is :

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const FormData = require('form-data');
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');


/**
 * This is a server config which should be merged on top of common config
 */
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    // This is our Express server for Dynamic universal
    server: './server.ts',
    // This is an example of Static prerendering (generative)
    prerender: './prerender.ts'
  },
  resolve: { extensions: [".js", ".ts"] },
  target: 'node',
  externals: [/(node_modules|main\..*\.js)/],
  output: {
    // Puts the output at the root of the dist folder
    path: path.join(__dirname),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  mode: 'development',

  node: {
    __dirname: false
  },
  //externals: [/(node_modules|main\..*\.js)/],
  /* externals: [nodeExternals({ whitelist: [/ngx-cookie/] })], */



  plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      // fixes WARNING Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
      /(.+)?angular(\\|\/)core(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'), // location of your src
      {} // a map of your routes
    ),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      // fixes WARNING Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
      /(.+)?express(\\|\/)(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      {}
    )
  ],

};
```

My server.ts file is:

```
const domino = require('domino');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const template = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '.', 'dist', 'index.html')).toString();
const win = domino.createWindow(template);
const files = fs.readdirSync(`${process.cwd()}/dist-server`);
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
const FormData = require('form-data');


win.fetch = fetch;
global['window'] = win;
global['document'] = win.document;
Object.defineProperty(win.document.body.style, 'transform', {
  value: () => {
    return {
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true
    };
  },
});

global['CSS'] = null;
// global['XMLHttpRequest'] = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;
global['Prism'] = null;

import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import * as express from 'express';
import * as compression from 'compression';
import * as cookieparser from 'cookie-parser';
const { provideModuleMap } = require('@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader');

const mainFiles = files.filter(file => file.startsWith('main'));
const hash = mainFiles[0].split('.')[1];
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require(`./dist-server/main.${hash}`);
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import { REQUEST, RESPONSE } from '@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens';
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
import { ROUTES } from './static.paths';

enableProdMode();

const app = express();
app.use(compression());
app.use(cookieparser());

const redirectowww = false;
const redirectohttps = true;
const wwwredirecto = true;
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  // for domain/index.html
  if (req.url === '/index.html') {
    res.redirect(301, 'https://' + req.hostname);
  }

  // check if it is a secure (https) request
  // if not redirect to the equivalent https url
  if (redirectohttps && req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] !== 'https' && req.hostname !== 'localhost') {
    // special for robots.txt
    if (req.url === '/robots.txt') {
      next();
      return;
    }
    res.redirect(301, 'https://' + req.hostname + req.url);
  }

  // www or not
  if (redirectowww && !req.hostname.startsWith('www.')) {
    res.redirect(301, 'https://www.' + req.hostname + req.url);
  }

  // www or not
  if (wwwredirecto && req.hostname.startsWith('www.')) {
    const host = req.hostname.slice(4, req.hostname.length);
    res.redirect(301, 'https://' + host + req.url);
  }

  next();
}
);

app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', 'src');

app.get('*.*', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '.', 'dist')));
app.get(ROUTES, express.static(path.join(__dirname, '.', 'static')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  global['navigator'] = req['headers']['user-agent'];
  const http = req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] === undefined ? 'http' : req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'];

  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
  console.time(`GET: ${req.originalUrl}`);
  res.render(
    '../dist/index',
    {
      req: req,
      res: res,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: REQUEST, useValue: (req)
        },
        {
          provide: RESPONSE, useValue: (res)
        },
        {
          provide: 'ORIGIN_URL',
          useValue: (`${http}://${req.headers.host}`)
        }
      ]
    },
    (err, html) => {
      if (!!err) { throw err; }

      // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
      console.timeEnd(`GET: ${req.originalUrl}`);
      res.send(html);
    });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`listening on http://localhost:${PORT}!`);
});
```

Comment: Browser's always right: `window.scroll` is not a function. Did you mean `window.onscroll`?

Comment: `node.js` does not have a window.

Comment: angular have window.scroll. it works fine in angular but when server side rendering is done. it throws and error. for window.scroll and formData.

Comment: Your using `domino` for rendering server side,.  So I assume domino has no support for `window.scroll`, and kind of makes sense as it's server side rendering.

Comment: @Keith thanks on that and what about formData issue?

Comment: Not sure about `FormData` as I can't see anything in your code that's accessing it.

Comment: i just updated my question!

Answer (score 5):

Import the following in your component,

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, PLATFORM_ID} from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser, isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'example-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) {

  }
  infunction() {
      if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
          window.scroll()
      }))
  }
}
```

Comment: How will this work on the browser then? or is not not necessary to sublement equivalent functionality because we're just waiting for the browser to load?

Comment: window, local-storage these methods are not available in the server-side. So these related tasks you can run in the browser block

Answer (score -1):

In app.component.ts import

```
import { WINDOW } from '@ng-toolkit/universal';
```

and inject

```
constructor(@Inject(WINDOW) private window: Window) {}


yourFunction(){
   this.window.scroll({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' }); 
}
```

don't forget to install @ng-toolkit/universal